# Mysql multiple max values from a table

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have below structure

```
+----+----+
| C1 | C2 |
+---------+
| 1  | A  |
| 2  | A  |
| 3  | A  |
| 4  | B  |
| 5  | B  |
| 6  | A  |
| 7  | C  |
+----+----+
```

Output should be

```
C1  C2    
3    A    
5    B    
6    A    
7    C
```

It should return the highest C1 value in each sequence that has the same value of C2

The simple group is not working, please guide how to achieve this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: are the C1 values consecutive without gaps?

Comment: @Nick No, it could be any

Comment: I have to find hightest of c1 till continuation of same value of c2

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Comment: The version is 5.6.10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you want records where no higher `c1` exists or the `c2` of the next higher `c1` is not equal to the current `c2`. You can get the next `c2` in a subquery ordering by `c1` using `LIMIT 1`.

```
SELECT t1.c1,
       t1.c2
       FROM elbat t1
       WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT t2.c2
                                FROM elbat t2
                                WHERE t2.c1 > t1.c1)
              OR (SELECT t2.c2
                         FROM elbat t2
                         WHERE t2.c1 > t1.c1
                         ORDER BY t2.c1
                         LIMIT 1) <> t1.c2;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=3c1c447d0907b190d5264b31cefb99ec)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by `LEFT JOIN`ing the table to itself on the next value in the table having a different `C2` value. We use a `GROUP BY` to get the last row in the table which has no match:

```
SELECT MAX(d1.C1) AS C1, MAX(d1.C2) AS C2
FROM data d1
LEFT JOIN data d2 ON d2.C2 != d1.C2
                 AND d2.C1 = (SELECT MIN(C1) FROM data d3 WHERE d3.C1 > d1.C1)
GROUP BY d2.C1
ORDER BY C1
```

Output:

```
C1  C2
3   A
5   B
6   A
7   C
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nA3pbM1hR2PDqzrdVrcjwt/1)

Answer (score 2):

You want the max c1 for each series of c2:

```
select t.* from tablename t
where 
  coalesce(
    (select c2 from tablename where c1 = (
      select min(c1) from tablename where c1 > t.c1)
    ), ''
  ) <> t.c2
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/o9ErVLhWhLBtPd7VHoHq2j/1).
Results:

```
| C1  | C2  |
| --- | --- |
| 3   | A   |
| 5   | B   |
| 6   | A   |
| 7   | C   |
```